# Getting Out of Memory error when using Image Classification in Sage Maker

Tags: amazon-web-services, artificial-intelligence, amazon-sagemaker

When using a p2.xlarge or p3.2xlarge with up to 1TB of memory trying to use the predefined SageMaker Image Classification algorithm in a training job I’m getting the following error:

`ClientError: Out of Memory. Please use a larger instance and/or reduce the values of other parameters (e.g. batch size, number of layers etc.) if applicable`

I’m using 450+ images, I’ve tried resizing them from their original 2000x3000px size to a 244x244px size down to a 24x24px size and keep getting the same error.

I’ve tried adjusting my hyper parameters: num_classes, num_layers, num_training_samples, optimizer, image_shape, checkpoint frequency, batch_size and epochs. Also tried using pretrained model. But the same error keeps occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would've added this as a comment but I don't have enough rep yet.

A few clarifying questions so that I can have some more context:

*How exactly are you achieving 1TB of RAM?*

1. [`p2.xlarge`](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/p2/) servers have 61GB of RAM, and [`p3.2xlarge`](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/p3/) servers have 61GB memory + 16GB onboard the Tesla V100 GPU.

*How are you storing, resizing, and ingesting the images into the SageMaker algorithm?*

2. The memory error seems suspect considering it still occurs when downsizing images to 24x24. If you are resizing your original images (450 images at 2000x3000 resolution) as in-memory objects and aren't performing the transformations in-place (ie: not creating new images), you may have a substantial bit of memory pre-allocated, causing the SageMaker training algorithm to throw an OOM error.

Comment: 1. Memory is the term used by SageMaker I’m pretty sure it means storage. 2. Images are already downsized in S3. I’m using Pipe Method, Augmented Manifest and S3SharedKey. RecordIO as wrapper.

Comment: My data is in S3 as JPEG.

Comment: Ok, that helps narrow it down a bit. Could you share the output from the CloudWatch logs? It may give us a better idea where the job is running out of memory.

Comment: I think the problem was that my categories were a string instead of an integer, now I have an InternalServerError with no other output.

Comment: Based on the logs, it doesn't look like training is ever initialized. The pretrained model needed for transfer learning might not even be loading due to the memory error. It sounds like there's a configuration issue causing this to error, I'd advise checking out this example notebook and making sure your setup is similar: 
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/imageclassification_caltech/Image-classification-transfer-learning.ipynb